# ¿Por qué no puedo maximizar una ventana en el segundo monitor?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Estoy tratando de maximizar la ventana de wpf en el segundo monitor, sin embargo, la ventana está maximizada en el monitor principal.

Si tomo la línea que maximiza la ventana, aparecerá en el segundo monitor normalmente, pero necesitaba el segundo monitor para maximizar todo, incluida la superposición de la barra de tareas.

```
public partial class view02 : Window
{
    public view02()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showInMonitor(1, this);
    }

    public void showInMonitor(int monitor, Window window)
    {
        List<Screen> screens = Screen.AllScreens.ToList();
        if (screens.Count > 1)
        {
            Screen screen = screens[monitor];
            if (!window.IsLoaded)
                window.WindowStartupLocation =
            WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            window.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Left;
            window.Top = screen.WorkingArea.Top;
            window.Width = screen.WorkingArea.Width;
            window.Height = screen.WorkingArea.Height;
            window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
}
```

¿Por qué no se maximiza en el segundo monitor?